# Would people like to have a blog?

Tags: discussion

I have been reading through I a lot of the answers on this site and I thought that it might be a good idea to start a blog, where we would have a theme each month around which a series of blog posts would be made. I would be willing to organize it. We could also do panel Q&As like on /r/AskHistorians, where questions that wouldn't always be allowed in the actual stack exchange were answered by a preselected panel of experts. Would people be interested?

Comment: For reference: [How are blogs created](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91407/how-are-blogs-created/91509#91509)

Comment: @T.E.D. that's out of date; see [this newer MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244467/162102).  When Worldbuilding asked for a blog [SE suggested we use Medium](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/2507/28), which has worked out reasonably well for us.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Interesting. I don't see any links to it anywhere on WorldBuilding though. How do users who weren't in on that Meta question a year ago find out it exists and/or where it is?

Comment: @T.E.D. two of our community ads are about the blog, we feed new blog posts into chat, and we have [other meta activity about the blog](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog).  It'd be nice if we could pin a blog link to the front page somewhere, but unfortunately we can't.  (Sometimes we feature meta posts.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Well, as a beta (and likely to stay there for the foreseable future) community ads aren't an option for us. Our chat probably isn't a good place for announcements either, for reasons I go into in my answer. I suppose a linked meta post for each blog post might do the job though.

Comment: @T.E.D. you can probably use meta somehow.  If posts are infrequent then a new post for each like you suggest would probably work fine; if posts are more frequent, you might want to organize it differently.  (For example, you might maintain a list of posts on meta sorted by type/topic, which would get bumped with each edit.)  I'm a visitor here so don't know what works best for this community in particular.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Well, as I said in my answer, I'm skeptical we really have the userbase to support such a thing right now, no matter what the mechanism for doing so is. However, it would be a good thing to have thought through should such a day come.

Comment: Yeah, you need people to make it work.  WB started with about half a dozen regular writers (and some occasional ones), and even so our blog activity dropped over the summer due to various absences, student schedules, etc.  If at some point in the future y'all want a blog and want to kibbitz with the Worldbuilding folks about ours, feel free to drop into our [chat room for the blog](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27736/universe-factory) or ask on our meta.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the kind info and advice. I've updated my answer with a little of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mod from WorldBuilding mentioned in the question comments that SE is actually [no longer supporting site blogs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244467/were-no-longer-starting-new-individual-site-community-blogs-heres-why). However, interested sites can still go out and [make them on their own](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2504/can-we-have-an-se-blog-for-this-site/2507#2507) externally.

I will say the thought has hit my head a time or two, but I'm sure most users here would much prefer I go clear off some of those flags instead. So I don't think I could add maintaining one to my own plate right now.

However, if our chatroom is any guide, I'm not sure there'd be much contribution there aside from myself.

It *would* be a great place to post things like book reviews, or "Good books on topic X", which lots of users want, but we are struggling to find a way to deal with now. I'm just not sure if the stack is ready for it.

Comment: Do you think they would object to it?

Comment: As a moderator, do you have any insight into how we could get one? @T.E.D.

Answer (score 2):

There are some answers that I have to downvote/vtc that I would prefer to see as blog posts - answers that are non-responsive, but interesting.  It would be nice to have the option to suggest that the answer be moved.

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe we could it would be a good idea, where wecould say show case the best answer of the day or offer to turn the best answer of the day into an essay which would be posted on the blog. This could act as an incentive for people to go above and beyond with their answers.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Blogs are a dime a dozen.  A well moderated Q&A site that cleans out the rubbish and has a good signal to noise ratio is both rare and *valuable*.   A blog is not value added.